# GLSL Tesselation Shader drawing triangles in different orientations for each patch

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, tesselation, gl-triangle-strip

I'm building a simple terrain on OpenGL using Tesselation Shaders and patches, but I'm having trouble with how OpenGL draws these patches. The triangles generated by OpenGL are being drawn in a different orientation for each patch, as shown in the pictures.

[Difference between triangles of neighbour patches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roxc7.png)

[Overview of different patches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnXWs.png)

I would like to know if there's a simple way to fix this problem, such as with some OpenGL built-in parameter, or it's necessary to reorient the triangles manually.

I'm using OpenGL 4.0. I'm creating a total of 8 patches, with my tessLevel set to 64.

Currently, this is how my code looks:

**Tesselation Control Shader**

```
#version 400

layout (vertices = 4) out;

uniform int tessLevel;
#define ID gl_InvocationID

void Preset();

void main()
{
    gl_out[ID].gl_Position = gl_in[ID].gl_Position;

    if (ID == 0)
    {
        Preset();
    }
}

void Preset()
{
    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = tessLevel;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = tessLevel;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = tessLevel;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[3] = tessLevel;

    gl_TessLevelInner[0] = tessLevel;
    gl_TessLevelInner[1] = tessLevel;
}
```

**Tesselation Evaluation Shader**

```
#version 400

layout(quads, equal_spacing, cw) in;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
out vec3 tesLightDirection;

vec4 CalculateInterpolatedPosition(float u, float v);

void main()
{
    float u = gl_TessCoord.x;
    float v = gl_TessCoord.y;

    vec4 interpolatedPosition = CalculateInterpolatedPosition(u, v);
    tesLightDirection = normalize(lightPos - interpolatedPosition.xyz);

    gl_Position = interpolatedPosition;
}

vec4 CalculateInterpolatedPosition(float u, float v)
{
    vec4 p0 = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    vec4 p1 = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    vec4 p2 = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    vec4 p3 = gl_in[3].gl_Position;

    return  p0 * (1 - u) * (1 - v) +
            p1 * u * (1 - v) +
            p3 * v * (1 - u) +
            p2 * u * v;
}
```

And my patches are being built in the following way, in my C++ program:

```
void Terrain::GenerateVertices()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPatches + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalPatches + 1; j++)
        {
            vertices.push_back(vec3(j, 0, i));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalPatches; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalPatches; j++)
        {
            int startingPoint = i * (totalPatches + 1) + j;

            indices.push_back(startingPoint);
            indices.push_back(startingPoint + 1);
            indices.push_back(startingPoint + totalPatches + 2);
            indices.push_back(startingPoint + totalPatches + 1);
        }
    }
}

void Terrain::Render(mat4 projection, mat4 view)
{
    shader.use();
    mat4 VPMatrix = projection * view;

    shader.setUniform("VP", VPMatrix);
    shader.setUniform("M", transform.modelMatrix());

    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 4);
    glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLubyte*)NULL);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to control the triangulation of the mesh. There are [some basic guarantees about how triangulation works](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Quads), but outside of those, it's up to the implementation. So whatever you're doing in your tessellator needs to be able to work with *any* (reasonable) triangulation.